# CSS: <a> tags not switching to hover state when HTML table row is highlighted

Tags: html, css

I'm building a site using a lot of HTML tables, styled with CSS.

I implemented an effect whereby hovering a row highlights the entire row:

```css
.table {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-color: #dee2e6;
    padding: 0.25rem 0.25rem;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

.table-bordered tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.table-hoverable tbody tr:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.table-hoverable div tr:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.table-hoverable a tr:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

My issue is that some text and images do not go in their hover state when row is highlighted, for example:

[image]

You can see that the first column (`<h2>` tags) and date column do change to white font, but the website and social media columns (`<a>` tags) do not.

Here is one page example Live:

https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/

and here the full CSS:

https://indexall.io/indeXall.css

How can I make it so that `<a>` tags - text or images - switch to their hover state when the row is highlighted?

### Reproducible example:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

.header
{
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header a
{
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

.footer
{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    margin: 0px;
}

.body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
}


/* CLICKABLE CELLS */

.clickable_cell
{
    font-family: 'Lato';
    /* width: 100px; */
    /* background-color: white; */
    /* height: 100px; */
}
.clickable_cell a
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left; 
}

.clickable_cell a:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }


/* LINKS */

a:link {
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  
a:visited {
    color: #da2222;
    /* text-align: center; */
    /* text-decoration: none; */
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }


  a:hover, a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

/* LINK TAGS */

.link_tag:link {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
    padding-left: 0.6em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_tag:visited {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
    padding-left: 0.6em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_tag:hover, .link_tag:active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

/* LINK FLAGS */

.link_flag:link {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    /* color: white; */
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_flag:visited {
    /* background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
    padding-left: 0.6em; */
    text-align: left;
    /* display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px; */
    /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_flag:hover, .link_flag:active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    /* text-decoration: underline; */
}


/* LINK COUNTRY */

.link_country:link {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    /* color: white; */
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    /* padding-right: 0.6em; */
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    /* padding-left: 0.6em; */
    text-align: left;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* text-decoration: none; */
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1.5px solid #000000;
    /* line-height: 5em; */
    font-size: 0.1rem;
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
}

.link_country:visited {
    /* background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
    padding-left: 0.6em; */
    text-align: left;
    /* display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px; */
    /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_country:hover, .link_country:active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    /* text-decoration: underline; */
}


/* ADD button */

.link_add:link {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 400;
    /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_add:visited {
    background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 400;
}

.link_add:hover, .link_add:active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 600;
}

h6, h5, h4, h3, h2, h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

h3 {
    font-size: calc(1.3rem + 0.6vw);
}

h4 {
    font-size: calc(1.275rem + 0.3vw);
}

h5 {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.table {
    /* width: 100%; */
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-color: #dee2e6;
    padding: 0.25rem 0.25rem;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    /* width:100%; messes up with index page */
    /* display: table; */
    max-width: 100%;
  }

.table-bordered tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    /* border-collapse: collapse; */
    /* display: block; */
}
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}

.table-hoverable tbody tr:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.table-hoverable div tr:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.table-hoverable a tr:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.table th {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-top: 0.33rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.33rem;
    /* display: table-cell; */
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.table td {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-top: 0.33rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.33rem;
    /* display: table-cell; */
    /* display: block; # collapses rows */
    text-align: left;
    /* vertical-align: top; */
}

.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ol,
ul {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

ol ol,
ul ul,
ol ul,
ul ol {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.small {
  font-size: 0.875em;
}

.country_div {
    vertical-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<table class="table table-hoverable table-bordered">

    <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">Website</th>
        <th scope="col">Social</th>
        <th scope="col">Country</th>
        <th scope="col">Est.</th>
        <th scope="col">Products</th>
    </tr>

    
    <tr>
        <td><h2>12 Gauge Microphones</h2></td>
        
        <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"> -->
        <td class="nowrap">
            
            <div>
                <a href="https://www.12gaugemicrophones.com/" target="_blank" id="12gaugemicrophones.com">12gaugemicrophones.com</a>
            </div>
        
        </td>

        <td class="nowrap"><a class="" href="https://twitter.com/12gaugemics" target="_blank" id="https://twitter.com/12gaugemics"><img alt="https://twitter.com/12gaugemics" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_twitter_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.youtube.com/c/12gaugemicrophones" target="_blank" id="https://www.youtube.com/c/12gaugemicrophones"><img alt="https://www.youtube.com/c/12gaugemicrophones" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_youtube_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_instagram_light.svg" alt="no_instagram_account" width="25" height="25" /> <a class="" href="https://www.facebook.com/12gaugemicrophones" target="_blank" id="https://www.facebook.com/12gaugemicrophones"><img alt="https://www.facebook.com/12gaugemicrophones" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_facebook_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a></td>

        <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/us" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/us.svg" alt="US" width="19" />US</div></a></td> -->
        <td class="nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/us" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/us.svg" alt="US" width="19" />US</div></a></td>

        <td>2011</td>
        <td><a class="link_tag" href='https://indexall.io/home-studio/products/audio' target='_self' id='audio'>Audio</a></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><h2>Ableton</h2></td>
        
        <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"> -->
        <td class="nowrap">
            
            <div>
                <a href="https://www.ableton.com" target="_blank" id="ableton.com">ableton.com</a>
            </div>
        
        </td>

        <td class="nowrap"><a class="" href="https://twitter.com/ableton" target="_blank" id="https://twitter.com/ableton"><img alt="https://twitter.com/ableton" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_twitter_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.youtube.com/ableton" target="_blank" id="https://www.youtube.com/ableton"><img alt="https://www.youtube.com/ableton" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_youtube_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.instagram.com/ableton" target="_blank" id="https://www.instagram.com/ableton"><img alt="https://www.instagram.com/ableton" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_instagram_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.facebook.com/ableton" target="_blank" id="https://www.facebook.com/ableton"><img alt="https://www.facebook.com/ableton" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_facebook_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a></td>

        <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/de" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/de.svg" alt="Germany" width="19" />Germany</div></a></td> -->
        <td class="nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/de" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/de.svg" alt="Germany" width="19" />Germany</div></a></td>

        <td>1999</td>
        <td><a class="link_tag" href='https://indexall.io/home-studio/products/software' target='_self' id='software'>Software</a> <a class="link_tag" href='https://indexall.io/home-studio/products/controllers' target='_self' id='controllers'>Controllers</a></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><h2>Adam Audio</h2></td>
        
        <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"> -->
        <td class="nowrap">
            
            <div>
                <a href="https://www.adam-audio.com/" target="_blank" id="adam-audio.com">adam-audio.com</a>
            </div>
        
        </td>

        <td class="nowrap"><a class="" href="https://twitter.com/adam_audio" target="_blank" id="https://twitter.com/adam_audio"><img alt="https://twitter.com/adam_audio" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_twitter_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/adamaudiospeakers" target="_blank" id="https://www.youtube.com/user/adamaudiospeakers"><img alt="https://www.youtube.com/user/adamaudiospeakers" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_youtube_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.instagram.com/adam_audio" target="_blank" id="https://www.instagram.com/adam_audio"><img alt="https://www.instagram.com/adam_audio" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_instagram_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.facebook.com/AdamProAudio" target="_blank" id="https://www.facebook.com/AdamProAudio"><img alt="https://www.facebook.com/AdamProAudio" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_facebook_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a></td>

        <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/de" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/de.svg" alt="Germany" width="19" />Germany</div></a></td> -->
        <td class="nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/de" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/de.svg" alt="Germany" width="19" />Germany</div></a></td>

        <td>1999</td>
        <td><a class="link_tag" href='https://indexall.io/home-studio/products/audio' target='_self' id='audio'>Audio</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Some icons are with <a> tag and some just img.

Comment: @Agan yes, this is by design: the ones with just ```<img>``` is when there is no social media handle. Only the ones with an actual link behind (ie existing handle) will have an ```<a>``` tag. You can see that those are not an issue because they are not white/black. Only the ones with an ```<a>``` tag have the issue.

Comment: @n1c you can not change the color for the image. Just use fontawesome and you can change it easy with: tr td:hover a { color: xyz;}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch color for your link as well as your social media icon.

I added this CSS:

```css
/* Change only text of the second td using :nth-child(2) when hovering the line */
tr:hover td:nth-child(2) a{
  color:white;
}
/* Change only social icon of the third td using :nth-child(3) when hovering the line */
tr:hover td:nth-child(3) a > img{
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(7499%) hue-rotate(230deg) brightness(99%) contrast(103%);
}
/* This will target img that are not in <a> tags */
tr:hover td:nth-child(3) img{
  filter: invert(73%) sepia(11%) saturate(14%) hue-rotate(329deg) brightness(91%) contrast(88%);
}
/* This will change color to twitter logo when you hover it */
tr:hover td:nth-child(3) a.twitter-logo > img:hover{
  filter: invert(51%) sepia(25%) saturate(5646%) hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(104%) contrast(90%);
}
```

The image filter is coming from [CSS filter generator to convert from black to target hex color](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp)

DEMO:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

.header
{
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header a
{
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

.footer
{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    margin: 0px;
}

.body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
}


/* CLICKABLE CELLS */

.clickable_cell
{
    font-family: 'Lato';
    /* width: 100px; */
    /* background-color: white; */
    /* height: 100px; */
}
.clickable_cell a
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left; 
}

.clickable_cell a:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }


/* LINKS */

a:link {
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  
a:visited {
    color: #da2222;
    /* text-align: center; */
    /* text-decoration: none; */
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }


  a:hover, a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

/* LINK TAGS */

.link_tag:link {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
    padding-left: 0.6em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_tag:visited {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
    padding-left: 0.6em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_tag:hover, .link_tag:active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

/* LINK FLAGS */

.link_flag:link {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    /* color: white; */
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_flag:visited {
    /* background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
    padding-left: 0.6em; */
    text-align: left;
    /* display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px; */
    /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_flag:hover, .link_flag:active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    /* text-decoration: underline; */
}

tr:hover td:nth-child(2) a{
  color:white;
}
tr:hover td:nth-child(3) a > img{
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(7499%) hue-rotate(230deg) brightness(99%) contrast(103%);
}
tr:hover td:nth-child(3) img{
  filter: invert(73%) sepia(11%) saturate(14%) hue-rotate(329deg) brightness(91%) contrast(88%);
}
tr:hover td:nth-child(3) a.twitter-logo > img:hover{
  filter: invert(51%) sepia(25%) saturate(5646%) hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(104%) contrast(90%);
}


/* LINK COUNTRY */

.link_country:link {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    /* color: white; */
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    /* padding-right: 0.6em; */
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    /* padding-left: 0.6em; */
    text-align: left;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* text-decoration: none; */
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1.5px solid #000000;
    /* line-height: 5em; */
    font-size: 0.1rem;
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
}

.link_country:visited {
    /* background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
    padding-left: 0.6em; */
    text-align: left;
    /* display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px; */
    /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_country:hover, .link_country:active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    /* text-decoration: underline; */
}


/* ADD button */

.link_add:link {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 400;
    /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_add:visited {
    background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 400;
}

.link_add:hover, .link_add:active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 600;
}

h6, h5, h4, h3, h2, h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

h3 {
    font-size: calc(1.3rem + 0.6vw);
}

h4 {
    font-size: calc(1.275rem + 0.3vw);
}

h5 {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.table {
    /* width: 100%; */
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-color: #dee2e6;
    padding: 0.25rem 0.25rem;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    /* width:100%; messes up with index page */
    /* display: table; */
    max-width: 100%;
  }

.table-bordered tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    /* border-collapse: collapse; */
    /* display: block; */
}
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}

.table-hoverable tbody tr:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.table-hoverable div tr:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.table-hoverable a tr:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.table th {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-top: 0.33rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.33rem;
    /* display: table-cell; */
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.table td {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-top: 0.33rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.33rem;
    /* display: table-cell; */
    /* display: block; # collapses rows */
    text-align: left;
    /* vertical-align: top; */
}

.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ol,
ul {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

ol ol,
ul ul,
ol ul,
ul ol {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.small {
  font-size: 0.875em;
}

.country_div {
    vertical-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<table class="table table-hoverable table-bordered">

    <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">Website</th>
        <th scope="col">Social</th>
        <th scope="col">Country</th>
        <th scope="col">Est.</th>
        <th scope="col">Products</th>
    </tr>

    
    <tr>
        <td><h2>12 Gauge Microphones</h2></td>
        
        <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"> -->
        <td class="nowrap">
            
            <div>
                <a href="https://www.12gaugemicrophones.com/" target="_blank" id="12gaugemicrophones.com">12gaugemicrophones.com</a>
            </div>
        
        </td>

        <td class="nowrap"><a class="twitter-logo" href="https://twitter.com/12gaugemics" target="_blank" id="https://twitter.com/12gaugemics"><img alt="https://twitter.com/12gaugemics" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_twitter_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.youtube.com/c/12gaugemicrophones" target="_blank" id="https://www.youtube.com/c/12gaugemicrophones"><img alt="https://www.youtube.com/c/12gaugemicrophones" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_youtube_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_instagram_light.svg" alt="no_instagram_account" width="25" height="25" /> <a class="" href="https://www.facebook.com/12gaugemicrophones" target="_blank" id="https://www.facebook.com/12gaugemicrophones"><img alt="https://www.facebook.com/12gaugemicrophones" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_facebook_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a></td>

        <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/us" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/us.svg" alt="US" width="19" />US</div></a></td> -->
        <td class="nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/us" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/us.svg" alt="US" width="19" />US</div></a></td>

        <td>2011</td>
        <td><a class="link_tag" href='https://indexall.io/home-studio/products/audio' target='_self' id='audio'>Audio</a></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><h2>Ableton</h2></td>
        
        <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"> -->
        <td class="nowrap">
            
            <div>
                <a href="https://www.ableton.com" target="_blank" id="ableton.com">ableton.com</a>
            </div>
        
        </td>

        <td class="nowrap"><a class="twitter-logo" href="https://twitter.com/ableton" target="_blank" id="https://twitter.com/ableton"><img alt="https://twitter.com/ableton" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_twitter_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.youtube.com/ableton" target="_blank" id="https://www.youtube.com/ableton"><img alt="https://www.youtube.com/ableton" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_youtube_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.instagram.com/ableton" target="_blank" id="https://www.instagram.com/ableton"><img alt="https://www.instagram.com/ableton" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_instagram_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.facebook.com/ableton" target="_blank" id="https://www.facebook.com/ableton"><img alt="https://www.facebook.com/ableton" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_facebook_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a></td>

        <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/de" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/de.svg" alt="Germany" width="19" />Germany</div></a></td> -->
        <td class="nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/de" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/de.svg" alt="Germany" width="19" />Germany</div></a></td>

        <td>1999</td>
        <td><a class="link_tag" href='https://indexall.io/home-studio/products/software' target='_self' id='software'>Software</a> <a class="link_tag" href='https://indexall.io/home-studio/products/controllers' target='_self' id='controllers'>Controllers</a></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><h2>Adam Audio</h2></td>
        
        <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"> -->
        <td class="nowrap">
            
            <div>
                <a href="https://www.adam-audio.com/" target="_blank" id="adam-audio.com">adam-audio.com</a>
            </div>
        
        </td>

        <td class="nowrap"><a class="twitter-logo" href="https://twitter.com/adam_audio" target="_blank" id="https://twitter.com/adam_audio"><img alt="https://twitter.com/adam_audio" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_twitter_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/adamaudiospeakers" target="_blank" id="https://www.youtube.com/user/adamaudiospeakers"><img alt="https://www.youtube.com/user/adamaudiospeakers" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_youtube_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.instagram.com/adam_audio" target="_blank" id="https://www.instagram.com/adam_audio"><img alt="https://www.instagram.com/adam_audio" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_instagram_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <a class="" href="https://www.facebook.com/AdamProAudio" target="_blank" id="https://www.facebook.com/AdamProAudio"><img alt="https://www.facebook.com/AdamProAudio" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_facebook_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a></td>

        <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/de" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/de.svg" alt="Germany" width="19" />Germany</div></a></td> -->
        <td class="nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/de" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/de.svg" alt="Germany" width="19" />Germany</div></a></td>

        <td>1999</td>
        <td><a class="link_tag" href='https://indexall.io/home-studio/products/audio' target='_self' id='audio'>Audio</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: That works! Thank you!! (pushed Live now)
Happy to have learned about ```nth-child(x)```.
How do I target the ```<a>``` and ```<img>``` tags differently though?
In the example, the Instagram icon of 12 Gauge Microphones (just an image, no link, because no Instagram account) should be grey in normal state and black when hovered (so it disappears when row is highlighted).

Comment: @n1c The Instagram from your example is actually not getting any change from the CSS I added. But I would recommend to add an extra filter for that like : `filter: invert(73%) sepia(11%) saturate(14%) hue-rotate(329deg) brightness(91%) contrast(88%);` I edited my answer this way you could validate it

Comment: implemented live, but does not seem to work (nore does it in the embedded snippet above), or perhaps I'm missing something? Icons still grey when hovered.
Do you have a good resource re ```filter:``` for me to read up on and understand how to tweak as needed?

Comment: @n1c which color do you want ? Here I choose [grey](https://html-color.codes/grey) so it is grey... the [filter generator](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp) is in the answer already. If you want to read the filter doc, it is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) or [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/)

Comment: @n1c I added another `hover` on the twitter logo to show it blue when you hover it. Just added a class `twitter-logo` on the twitter links. You could do the same on the other logo if you wish, using the filter

Comment: Thank You @MaxiGui! Managed to make it work by tweaking the filter (the generator works from black and my default svg is white, so generator output wasn't correct).
Very much appreciate your help - live now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply a wrong order for hover selectors: the `div` and `a` are descendants of `tr` elements. Therefore selector should be `tr:hover a` instead of `a tr:hober`.

```css
.table-hoverable tr:hover div {
    background-color:#000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.table-hoverable tr:hover a {
    background-color:#000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: That's great - simple and easy, and good to know, thank you! Solved the simple links (website) BUT messed up my Country and Products tags, and did not resolve my Social links (images) :/
I will try MaxiGui's approach which seems to address both.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the `:hover`-effect on the parent element and, optionally, use the **descendant child combinator** `>` on the elements you want to style. Keep in mind when using this combinator, the element has to be a child of that parent - so use a nested selector such as `tr:hover > td a img`.

Also, you can't change the color of an image SVG. You can, however, [use the `filter`-hack to change its color](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp), which works really good for achromatic colors such as black, white and grey.

```css
tr:hover>td,
tr:hover>td a {
  color: white;
}

tr:hover>td a img:not(td a.link_flag img) {
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(288deg) brightness(102%) contrast(102%);
}

tr:hover > td a.link_flag .country_div {
color: black;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header a {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  margin: 0px;
}

.body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
}


/* CLICKABLE CELLS */

.clickable_cell {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  /* width: 100px; */
  /* background-color: white; */
  /* height: 100px; */
}

.clickable_cell a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
}

.clickable_cell a:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* LINKS */

a:link {
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
  color: #da2222;
  /* text-align: center; */
  /* text-decoration: none; */
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* LINK TAGS */

.link_tag:link {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
  padding-bottom: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 0.6em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_tag:visited {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
  padding-bottom: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 0.6em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_tag:hover,
.link_tag:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 2px solid white;
}


/* LINK FLAGS */

.link_flag:link {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* color: white; */
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_flag:visited {
  /* background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
    padding-left: 0.6em; */
  text-align: left;
  /* display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px; */
  /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_flag:hover,
.link_flag:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  /* text-decoration: underline; */
}


/* LINK COUNTRY */

.link_country:link {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* color: white; */
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  /* padding-right: 0.6em; */
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
  /* padding-left: 0.6em; */
  text-align: left;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  /* text-decoration: none; */
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1.5px solid #000000;
  /* line-height: 5em; */
  font-size: 0.1rem;
  /* vertical-align: middle; */
}

.link_country:visited {
  /* background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
    padding-left: 0.6em; */
  text-align: left;
  /* display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px; */
  /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_country:hover,
.link_country:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  /* text-decoration: underline; */
}


/* ADD button */

.link_add:link {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 400;
  /* line-height: 5em; */
}

.link_add:visited {
  background-color: black;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 400;
}

.link_add:hover,
.link_add:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 600;
}

h6,
h5,
h4,
h3,
h2,
h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: calc(1.3rem + 0.6vw);
}

h4 {
  font-size: calc(1.275rem + 0.3vw);
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.table {
  /* width: 100%; */
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #212529;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-color: #dee2e6;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.25rem;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  /* width:100%; messes up with index page */
  /* display: table; */
  max-width: 100%;
}

.table-bordered tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* border-collapse: collapse; */
  /* display: block; */
}

.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.table-hoverable tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.table-hoverable div tr:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.table-hoverable a tr:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.table th {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-top: 0.33rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.33rem;
  /* display: table-cell; */
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.table td {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-top: 0.33rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.33rem;
  /* display: table-cell; */
  /* display: block; # collapses rows */
  text-align: left;
  /* vertical-align: top; */
}

.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ol,
ul {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

ol ol,
ul ul,
ol ul,
ul ol {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.small {
  font-size: 0.875em;
}

.country_div {
  vertical-align: center;
}

tr:hover>td,
tr:hover>td a {
  color: white;
}

tr:hover>td a img:not(td a.link_flag img) {
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(288deg) brightness(102%) contrast(102%);
}

tr:hover > td a.link_flag .country_div {
color: black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hoverable table-bordered">

  <tr>
    <th scope="col"></th>
    <th scope="col">Website</th>
    <th scope="col">Social</th>
    <th scope="col">Country</th>
    <th scope="col">Est.</th>
    <th scope="col">Products</th>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>
      <h2>12 Gauge Microphones</h2>
    </td>

    <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"> -->
    <td class="nowrap">

      <div>
        <a href="https://www.12gaugemicrophones.com/" target="_blank" id="12gaugemicrophones.com">12gaugemicrophones.com</a>
      </div>

    </td>

    <td class="nowrap">
      <a class="" href="https://twitter.com/12gaugemics" target="_blank" id="https://twitter.com/12gaugemics"><img alt="https://twitter.com/12gaugemics" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_twitter_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
      <a class="" href="https://www.youtube.com/c/12gaugemicrophones" target="_blank" id="https://www.youtube.com/c/12gaugemicrophones"><img alt="https://www.youtube.com/c/12gaugemicrophones" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_youtube_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a> <img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_instagram_light.svg" alt="no_instagram_account"
        width="25" height="25" />
      <a class="" href="https://www.facebook.com/12gaugemicrophones" target="_blank" id="https://www.facebook.com/12gaugemicrophones"><img alt="https://www.facebook.com/12gaugemicrophones" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_facebook_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
    </td>

    <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/us" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/us.svg" alt="US" width="19" />US</div></a></td> -->
    <td class="nowrap">
      <a class="link_flag" href="https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/us" target="_self">
        <div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/us.svg" alt="US" width="19" />US</div>
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>2011</td>
    <td><a class="link_tag" href='https://indexall.io/home-studio/products/audio' target='_self' id='audio'>Audio</a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <h2>Ableton</h2>
    </td>

    <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"> -->
    <td class="nowrap">

      <div>
        <a href="https://www.ableton.com" target="_blank" id="ableton.com">ableton.com</a>
      </div>

    </td>

    <td class="nowrap">
      <a class="" href="https://twitter.com/ableton" target="_blank" id="https://twitter.com/ableton"><img alt="https://twitter.com/ableton" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_twitter_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
      <a class="" href="https://www.youtube.com/ableton" target="_blank" id="https://www.youtube.com/ableton"><img alt="https://www.youtube.com/ableton" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_youtube_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
      <a class="" href="https://www.instagram.com/ableton" target="_blank" id="https://www.instagram.com/ableton"><img alt="https://www.instagram.com/ableton" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_instagram_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
      <a class="" href="https://www.facebook.com/ableton" target="_blank" id="https://www.facebook.com/ableton"><img alt="https://www.facebook.com/ableton" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_facebook_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
    </td>

    <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/de" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/de.svg" alt="Germany" width="19" />Germany</div></a></td> -->
    <td class="nowrap">
      <a class="link_flag" href="https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/de" target="_self">
        <div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/de.svg" alt="Germany" width="19" />Germany</div>
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>1999</td>
    <td><a class="link_tag" href='https://indexall.io/home-studio/products/software' target='_self' id='software'>Software</a> <a class="link_tag" href='https://indexall.io/home-studio/products/controllers' target='_self' id='controllers'>Controllers</a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <h2>Adam Audio</h2>
    </td>

    <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"> -->
    <td class="nowrap">

      <div>
        <a href="https://www.adam-audio.com/" target="_blank" id="adam-audio.com">adam-audio.com</a>
      </div>

    </td>

    <td class="nowrap">
      <a class="" href="https://twitter.com/adam_audio" target="_blank" id="https://twitter.com/adam_audio"><img alt="https://twitter.com/adam_audio" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_twitter_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
      <a class="" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/adamaudiospeakers" target="_blank" id="https://www.youtube.com/user/adamaudiospeakers"><img alt="https://www.youtube.com/user/adamaudiospeakers" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_youtube_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
      <a class="" href="https://www.instagram.com/adam_audio" target="_blank" id="https://www.instagram.com/adam_audio"><img alt="https://www.instagram.com/adam_audio" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_instagram_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
      <a class="" href="https://www.facebook.com/AdamProAudio" target="_blank" id="https://www.facebook.com/AdamProAudio"><img alt="https://www.facebook.com/AdamProAudio" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/logos/logo_facebook_black.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
    </td>

    <!-- <td class="clickable_cell nowrap"><a class="link_flag" href = "https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/de" target = "_self"><div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/de.svg" alt="Germany" width="19" />Germany</div></a></td> -->
    <td class="nowrap">
      <a class="link_flag" href="https://indexall.io/home-studio/brands/de" target="_self">
        <div class="country_div"><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/vhucnsp9j1u/flags/de.svg" alt="Germany" width="19" />Germany</div>
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>1999</td>
    <td><a class="link_tag" href='https://indexall.io/home-studio/products/audio' target='_self' id='audio'>Audio</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you @Sigurd Mazanti - similar approach to MaxiGui using ```filter``` it seems, which I have just implemented. Need to figure out how to operate this (ie how to use the variables in the filter).
I see your approach is targeting specific tags instead of using ```nth-child(x)``` - not sure if there are benefits to this instead?

Comment: You could look into using something like [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) - that will convert your SVG images into fonts, so you can use `font-size`, `color` and other associated properties to style your SVG images, instead of using `filter.`

Comment: The difference between using e.g. `td:nth-child(2)` and the descendant selector `>` is that, if you sometime in the future would like to implement another element into the `td`-container that's **before** the second child, that elements styling would be set with `td:nth-child(2)`, as the element you styled originally would now be the third child (`td:nth-child(3)`). That's why I'd always opt to use classnames if they're available. With `>`, the selector has to be child - so if you were to use a new container around the `td`, it also wouldn't work. @n1c